# Calculate Hamming weight and/or distance in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, hamming-distance, hammingweight, vba

I’m trying to compare clients, two by two, whose qualities can be defined by binary choices (for example a client uses a product or not).
After much search online, it looks like I’d need to use the Hamming Distance for that, or its equivalent:  find the Hamming Weight to the result of an XOR operation between two words.

For a concrete example, **Hamming distance between 1001 & 1011:**

> Calculate the number 1001 XOR 1011= 0010
>   Hamming weight of 0010 = 1 (numbers of bit set to
>   1 in 0010)

I need to do  that in for words up to 96 bits.

I found some information on

http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/HammingDistance.html

http://trustedsignal.blogspot.ca/2015/06/xord-play-normalized-hamming-distance.html

and plenty of pieces of code , for example

[Hamming weight written only in binary operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946115/hamming-weight-written-only-in-binary-operations)

but only in C, Java , Perl, O, opencl... anything but Excel VBA.

So far, here’s what I manage to put together.

It works, but unfortunately **only for words of 30 bits or less**, and uses a somewhat crude method: XOR on the two numbers X and Y, then convert to a string that represent the binary number. Then count the length of the string once the 1’s are taken out. I guess there’s a more elegant and efficient way.

```
Public Function HamDist(x As Long, y As Long, NbBit As Integer)

Dim i As Long, BinStrg As String, bxor As Long 

bxor = x Xor y 

BinStrg = "" 

For i = NbBit To 0 Step -1 ‘going from left to right 
         If bxor And (2 ^ i) Then
            BinStrg = BinStrg + "1" ‘add a 1 to the string 
         Else
            BinStrg = BinStrg + "0"
         End If
      Next

 HamDist = Len(BinStrg) - Len(Replace(BinStrg, "1", "")) ' replace the 1 by nothing and count  the length of the resulting string 
End Function
```

Can you help make it works **for 96 bit words in VBA for Excel 2010** and below (udf or sub), either by calculating the hamming weight or distance ?

Comment: Your `x` and `y` can't be `Long`. For 96 bits, you'll have to work with strings as inputs rather than `Integer`, `Long`, `LongLong`, or `Double`, since these all store 64 or fewer bits. This is unwieldy and requires you to write large number arithmetic functions [like here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/misc_tutorials/project_euler/LargeNumberArithmetic.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the chain of qualities in String form (e.g. a String consisting only of the letters 'T' and 'F'), this could quite easily be done using a loop.

```
Function hammingDistance(qualities1 As String, qualities2 As String) As Integer

    If Len(qualities1) <> Len(qualities2) Then
        hammingDistance = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim i, result As Integer
    result = 0

    For i = 1 To Len(qualities1)
        If Mid(qualities1, i, 1) <> Mid(qualities2, i, 1) Then result = result + 1
    Next

    hammingDistance = result

End Function
```